# Generating a Random Number with Precision in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, random

I've got this function:

```
Number.random = function(minimum, maximum, precision) {
    minimum = minimum === undefined ? 0 : minimum;
    maximum = maximum === undefined ? 9007199254740992 : maximum;
    precision = precision === undefined ? 0 : precision;

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;

    return random;
}
```

Right now precision is not implemented, does anyone have any good ideas on how I can implement it? The purpose of the precision option is to give you a fixed number of multiple decimal places out, e.g.:

```
// A number from 0 to 10 that will always come back with two decimal places
Number.random(0, 10, 2); // 3.14
```

Comment: With the range that you are generating then the result will have to be a `string` if it is to be representable. Or you will need change the range if you want to represent the return as a number.

Comment: Is the range too large? What is the largest I can go without having to switch to a string?

Comment: I believe it it is 17 significant figures. Would have to double check that. So I guess it depends on what you want as values of `precision`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Number.random = function(minimum, maximum, precision) {
    minimum = minimum === undefined ? 0 : minimum;
    maximum = maximum === undefined ? 9007199254740992 : maximum;
    precision = precision === undefined ? 0 : precision;

    var random = Math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum;

    return random.toFixed(precision);
}
```

It uses [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function to set the precision

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2rFW8/1/**

Comment: I suppose this could work:
return Number(random.toFixed(precision));

Comment: Or `return parseFloat(random.toFixed(precision));` thanks @reaxis

Comment: And if you try something like `console.log(Number.random(undefined, undefined, 3));` instead of `console.log(Number.random(3, 5, 3));`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try multiplying the number by `10^precision`, rounding it, then dividing it by `10^precision`. That will give you the result you want. Below is a crude implementation of this logic. You may want to add some error checking on the precision argument, or using some other way to calculate (such as `Math.pow`), though.

```
Number.random = function(minimum, maximum, precision) {
    minimum = minimum === undefined ? 0 : minimum;
    maximum = maximum === undefined ? 9007199254740992 : maximum;
    precision = precision === undefined ? 0 : precision;

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;

    for (var i = 0; i < precision; i++) {
        random = random * 10;
    }
    random = Math.round(random);
    for (var i = 0; i < precision; i++) {
        random = random / 10;
    }

    return random;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     Number.random = function(minimum, maximum, precision) {
     minimum = minimum||0;
     maximum = maximum ||9007199254740992;
    precision =precision ||0;

    var random = Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1) + minimum;

    return random.toFixed(precision);
  }

 //call Number.random(0,10.10,3)
```

Comment: `Math.floor` will kinda kill the decimals, no?

Comment: Thank you @YuriyGalanter I removed the `floor` function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Number.random = function(minimum, maximum, precision) {
    minimum = minimum === undefined ? 0 : minimum;
    maximum = maximum === undefined ? 9007199254740992 : maximum;
    precision = precision === undefined ? 0 : precision;

    var random = Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1) + minimum;

    return Math.round(random * Math.pow(10, precision)) / Math.pow(10, precision);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't defined any limits w.r.t. the `precision` you may want, and bearing in mind the limitations (accurate numeric representation) of `Number` in Javascript then you may find a `string` representation acceptable. In which case you may want to do something like this.

Javascript

```
var maxInteger = 9007199254740992;

function randomInteger(minimum, maximum) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
}

Number.random = function (minimum, maximum, precision) {
    minimum = typeof minimum !== 'number' ? 0 : minimum;
    minimum = minimum < -maxInteger ? -maxInteger : minimum;
    maximum = typeof maximum !== 'number' || maximum > maxInteger ? maxInteger : maximum;
    precision = typeof precision !== 'number' || precision < 0 ? 0 : precision;

    var random = randomInteger(minimum, maximum).toString(),
        decimals;

    if (precision) {
        decimals = '';
        while (decimals.length < precision) {
            decimals += randomInteger(0, maxInteger)
        }

        random += '.' + decimals.slice(0, precision);
    }

    return random;
}

console.log(Number.random(-maxInteger, maxInteger, 40));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/VAfNS/)